# Android - Open links in YouTube app by default

Tags: android, web, view, youtube

Ok so I have some links in a web view that link to youtube videos. When the user clicks on the link in the web view, they get a 'complete action using' popup. Is there anyway I can listen for `<a href="http://youtube.com/videoid"></a>` and if that is the case refer the user to the youtube app, playing the correct video? Essentially I just want all youtube links to be opened by default in the youtube app.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a custom WebViewClient and override shouldOverrideUrlLoading.
This function is being called before the webview goes into the address. There, you should check if the link is a youtube link and if so, open an intent as user6363583 said, and return true, else return false.
Dont forget to set your custom Web client as your webview Web client... Just use: webview.setWebViewClient(yourClient)

Comment: Ok thanks. Are there any tutorials on this I could take a look at? Also is there no way to do this directly from the a href?

Comment: You can take a look here, just replace the loadUrl function with the youtube intent code (of course, you should also change the condition to fit your needs): http://lexandera.com/2009/02/intercepting-page-loads-in-webview/

Comment: Hmm maybe I haven't explained myself clearly enough. I have an HTML page that I am loading into the web view and in that web page there are some a href links that go to youtube. If clicked I would like the url to open directly int the youtube app without the 'complete action using' popup box appearing.

Comment: Oh OK... Just add this line: intent.setClassName("com.google.android.youtube", "com.google.android.youtube.WatchActivity");

Comment: Where would I add it? I now have this: http://pastebin.com/0bwmT6D9 so where would I place the other answerers code? thank you for helping

Comment: Replace you shouldOverrideUrlLoading function with this one: http://pastebin.com/DruJmNYY I'm writing from my phone so there could be errors in the code... But it should be easy to understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112609/discussion-between-dwinnbrown-and-shalev-moyal).

Comment: Hi Again. Is it possible to load the popup 'complete action using' if youtube is not installed instead of just opening up the youtube website within the app?

Comment: App crashes when clicking the link...two console errors `05-23 15:30:43.466 6283-6283/com.example.dwinnbrown.myapplicationv20 A/chromium: [FATAL:jni_android.cc(249)] Check failed: false. Please include Java exception stack in crash report` and `05-23 15:30:43.636 6283-6283/com.example.dwinnbrown.myapplicationv20 A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 6283 (yapplicationv20)`

Answer (score 0):

Here it is

```
Intent intent =newIntent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("vnd.youtube://"+ id));
startActivity(intent);
```

See,

```
private void showVideo(String videoID){
Intent intent =newIntent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("vnd.youtube://"+ videoId));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And when you have a video link to open then call this method.

Suppose a video link YouTube.com/watch?v=asdfg

So, to open this video on YouTube call

```
showVideo("asdfg");
```

That's it.

Comment: Thanks. Where specifically would I put that though as I am going from a web view? Also would I have to specify the id of the video as the links have different id's?

Comment: You can use this as a method. And On your link clicking event, call the method

Comment: Sorry bit of a n00b so how would I call this intent method from an `<a href>`?

Comment: Thank you. Bear with me but how do I call the open video from an a href link? Can I use `onclick`?

Comment: Create a webclient and on your webview use webview.setWebViewClient(yourclient). And on it's method shouldOverrideUrlLoading call your showVideo(String link) method

Comment: Please checkout this link for a moment http://javatechig.com/android/android-webview-example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112606/discussion-between-dwinnbrown-and-user6363583).

Comment: Ah, if u don't mind. I am working in a project now. I am quite busy. You can continue here with short problems, please!

Comment: Ok no problem :) Thanks for the help anyway